# torchvisionのimage.pydが見つからない

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

初めまして。ネット上で調べましたが、解決策が無くて困っています

pytorchを使いたいと思い、torchとtorchvisionをインストールしたのですが、torchvisionをインポートすると
下記Warningが発生します。

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.optim as optim


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

> C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pukatorch5\venv\lib\site-packages\torchvision\io\image.py:11: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: Could not find module 'C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\pukatorch5\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\image.pyd' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
> warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")

Could not find moduleと言われたパスを見に行ったのですが、image.pydは存在しており、どうしたらよいのかわかりません。ご教授いただけると幸いです

Package           Version

---

numpy             1.21.4
Pillow            8.4.0
pip               21.3.1
setuptools        40.8.0
torch             1.10.1+cu102
torchaudio        0.10.1+cu102
torchvision       0.11.2+cu102
typing_extensions 4.0.1

Pythonのバージョンは3.8です。

Comment: とりあえず着手して使い方を見るだけならCUDA版ではなくCPU版に切り替えて使ってみるとか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

CPU版に切り替えたところWarningは出なくなりました。そこでCudaのバージョンをcu102からcu101に下げたところ、Warningも発生しなくなりました。アドバイスありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

Cudaのバージョンをcu102からcu101に下げたところ、Warningが発生しなくなりました。

```
Package           Version
----------------- -----------
numpy             1.21.4
Pillow            8.4.0
pip               21.3.1
setuptools        40.8.0
torch             1.7.1+cu101
torchaudio        0.7.2
torchvision       0.8.2+cu101
typing_extensions 4.0.1
```